# Green Hosting Rails App Hosting Germany / Europe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting

Are there any green web hosting providers for a rails application with mysql on a virtual/shared server preferentially in germany (or europe in general but less preferred)? (Small Business Solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://shellycloud.com/ has a data center from Hetzner in Germany, which uses green energy: http://www.hetzner.de/en/hosting/unternehmen/umweltschutz. It is Rails hosting on a virtual server, but from SQL databases supports only PostgreSQL at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

railscomplete.de offers [rails hosting in germany](http://railscomplete.de) - on virtual servers and dedicated hardware.